# .Add triggers RoutedEvent="Loaded" but .Insert does not

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to trigger an animation in my View when a new item is added to an ListBox via a binding to a ViewModel's ObservableCollection. The binding works great.

The animation is tied to the RoutedEvent "Loaded" on the ListBox.ItemContainer style. When I use .Add to add a new item, the animation correctly triggers on the new item only, but .Add can only add items at the end of the ObservableCollection. My ObservableCollection is sorted, so this doesn't work. I think I have three options:

1) Add the item and then re-sort the list
2) Insert the item at the correct location
3) Sort the list in XAML

I have not been able to get option 1) to work as ObservableCollection doesn't have .Sort() (to sort the list in place) and .OrderBy(x => x.TimeStamp) requires recreating the collection, which makes all items fire the Loaded RoutedEvent (i.e. they all animate, and I only want the new item to animate). I have also tried sorting in place using .ToList().Sort() but that seems to new up a list that is sorted and discarded...

I haven't been able to get 2) to work correctly. .Add works correctly and triggers the Loaded animation for the new item only, but places the item at the end of the list where it does not belong. I can use .Insert to insert the item at the correct location; however, .Insert does not trigger the animation on the newly inserted item.

I haven't been able to get 3) to work at all, and the examples provided online seem needlessly complex for something that should be a one-liner.

Here is the animation code I am using:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ScaleTransform x:Name="transform" />
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                                        <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.ScaleY" From="0" Duration="0:0:0.4"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </EventTrigger.Actions>
                                    </EventTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

I am inserting items like this for testing (Insert):

```
                var timelineItem = new TimelineItem("Test", DateTime.UtcNow);
                Timeline.Insert(0, timelineItem);
                OnPropertyChanged("Timeline");
```

I am adding items like this for testing (Add):

```
                var timelineItem = new TimelineItem("Test", DateTime.UtcNow);
                Timeline.Add(timelineItem);
                OnPropertyChanged("Timeline");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you see this difference is because of the way templated controls are re-used in a ListBox. It's the ui controls being loaded that drives your current animation and they're already loaded if you insert.

Unfortunately, datacontextchanged is not a routedevent so you'd need a behaviour or something to use that to start an animation.

I suggest you use a datatrigger instead.

Add a bool "IsLoading" public property to whatever your row viewmodel is.

Set that to true when you want the loading animation.

Use a datatrigger based on IsLoading=true instead of an eventtrigger.

Use an async method in your row viewmodel with an await Task.Delay(2000) to set it false a second or two after the viewmodel is inserted ( or added ).

The datatrigger approach has the benefit that when you initially show 20 entries you can choose which (if any of them) animate.